# Нужна ли запятая в «направлен на тему(,) связанную с разработкой»?

Tags: пунктуация

Нужна ли запятая между словами «тему» и «связанную»?

> Метку можно использовать, если вопрос направлен на **тему связанную** с разработкой веб-приложений.

Спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да, конечно, запятая нужна: это новый причастный оборот с определяемым словом в препозиции.

Корректно: *Метку можно использовать, если вопрос направлен на тему, связанную с разработкой веб-приложений*.

Мне кажется, лучше звучать будет так: *Метку можно использовать для вопросов, связанных с разработкой веб-приложений*.